# Nested verbatims

Tags: verbatim

If I want to write a text how to use `verbatim` in TeX I would simply give an example like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
   How to use verbatim in TeX:
\begin{verbatim}
  start with \begin{verbatim}
  and end with \end{verbatim}
   And now you have to write
\end{verbatim}
 In your own
\end{document}
```

Than it won't compile due to the first `\end{verbatim}`. One solution I've found looks like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
    The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
    \begin{Verbatim}[breaklines=true]
        This is a very long line that will need to be broken into pieces otherwise it will run into and out of the margins
        \begin{verbatim}
            test
        \end{verbatim}
     And now you have to write
    \end{Verbatim}
   on your own
\end{document}
```

i.e. to stack them with different environments. Does there exist a different solution as well? So my request is if there is same environment definition on which I don't have to switch between different `verbatim`/`Verbatim`/etc.

Comment: I don't know any way of doing this, because it's the literal `\end{verbatim}` that is looked for to end a verbatim block, but the example would be even more interesting if you include something between the two `\end` commands.

Comment: You mean the way I did?

Comment: You can't use verbatim, its deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *might* think to use a stack, but it would require very deep surgery and would not solve the issue if the inner `verbatim` is not balanced. I don't think you have so many `verbatim` environments in which `\end{verbatim}` appears.

Sorry, but the most practical solution (and probably the only feasible one) is to use a different name for the outer environment. If you don't want to use `fancyvrb`, you can use the older `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{overbatim}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
\begin{overbatim}
This is a line to start; never indent `verbatim'
unless you really want indented lines
\begin{verbatim}
test
\end{verbatim}
And now you have to write
\end{overbatim}
on your own

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `fancyvrb`, if you want to nest `Verbatim` inside

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{oVerbatim}{Verbatim}{}

\begin{document}

    The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
    \begin{oVerbatim}[breaklines=true]
        This is a very long line that will need to be broken into pieces otherwise it will run into and out of the margins
        \begin{Verbatim}
            test
        \end{Verbatim}
     And now you have to write
    \end{oVerbatim}
   on your own

The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
\begin{oVerbatim}[breaklines=true]
This is a very long line that will need to be broken into pieces otherwise it will run into and out of the margins
\begin{Verbatim}
test
\end{Verbatim}
And now you have to write
\end{oVerbatim}
on your own

\end{document}
```

[image]

And you see why I recommend never indenting verbatim environments.

If you want to pass `breaklines=true` to all `oVerbatim` environments, you can exploit the last argument to `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment`, which accepts any list of `fancyvrb` options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{oVerbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines=true}

\begin{document}

    The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
    \begin{oVerbatim}[breaklines=true]
        This is a very long line that will need to be broken into pieces otherwise it will run into and out of the margins
        \begin{Verbatim}
            test
        \end{Verbatim}
     And now you have to write
    \end{oVerbatim}
   on your own

The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks:
\begin{oVerbatim}
This is a very long line that will need to be broken into pieces otherwise it will run into and out of the margins
\begin{Verbatim}
test
\end{Verbatim}
And now you have to write
\end{oVerbatim}
on your own

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well the indention was not intended :-) The `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` is finally what I'm looking for. But somehow I don't find it in the documentation. Therefore an additional question: is it possible to define the environment as well with the optional, i.e. that `[breaklines=true]` is already included in the command?

Comment: @LeO That's the purpose of the last argument to `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment`, which can take any list of options. For instance, `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{oVerbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines=true}`

Comment: Thx for the hint. I had no idea what the additonal `{}` would be good for. I don't want to update your sample - don't know if that's a good idea or looking in the comments.

Comment: @LeO I added it

Answer (score 4):

There are pretty much only two solutions: One is to use a differently-named `verbatim` environment as you did, because the `verbatim` environment is actually looking for the literal string `\end{verbatim}` for its end. This is a general issue with verbatim printing in any markup language.

The other option is to use `\verbatiminput` from the `verbatim` package to include the desired `verbatim` text from an external file. (`fancyvrb` provides an equivalent `\VerbatimInput` command if you prefer that package's functionality).

Comment: Hmmm about the second option: is there a way to write the content at the very beginning into a file (from within LuaLaTex)? Perhaps at the very beginning of the tex file?

Comment: You could use `fancyvrb`'s `VerbatimOut` environment to do the job. I've used similar functionality to enable typing answers to exercises with the questions but printing them at the end of the chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your encoding this may work or not.

I introduced a zero-width space (unicode U+200B) between `\` and `end` to break the inner `\end` command functionnaly but not visually and it renders just fine:

```
\begin{verbatim}\begin{verbatim}\​end{verbatim}\end{verbatim}
```

[image]

This zero-width space is, understandably, invisible in the code above. Overleaf's editor renders it as a red line with a small tack:

[image]